# How to use "where" clausule with graphQL in OpenAPI-to-GraphQL server?

Tags: graphql, loopback, loopback4

I'm using LoopBack 4 with oasgraph (renamed to OpenAPI-to-GraphQL).
One of my OpenAPI endpoint has a `filter` parameter with the following schema :

```
"parameters": [
          {
            "name": "filter",
            "in": "query",
            "style": "deepObject",
            "explode": true,
            "schema": {
              "properties": {
                "where": {
                  "type": "object"
                },
                "fields": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "id": {
                      "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "idOwner": {
                      "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "createdTimestamp": {
                      "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "modifiedTimestamp": {
                      "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "idUserCreated": {
                      "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "idUserModified": {
                      "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "value": {
                      "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "dicContactId": {
                      "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "counterpartyId": {
                      "type": "boolean"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "offset": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "minimum": 0
                },
                "limit": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "minimum": 0
                },
                "skip": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "minimum": 0
                },
                "order": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                },
                "include": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "relation": {
                        "type": "string"
                      },
                      "scope": {
                        "properties": {
                          "where": {
                            "type": "object"
                          },
                          "fields": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {}
                          },
                          "offset": {
                            "type": "integer",
                            "minimum": 0
                          },
                          "limit": {
                            "type": "integer",
                            "minimum": 0
                          },
                          "skip": {
                            "type": "integer",
                            "minimum": 0
                          },
                          "order": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                              "type": "string"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "type": "object"
            }
          }
        ],
```

As you can see the `where` properity is of a type "object". However in graphQL editor it expects a String:

[graphql editor - expected type string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAQwX.png)

The problem is that the string produces an error when I run a query:

[graphql editor - where clause is not an object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSDHu.png)

As a result, I'm not able to perform a query with `where` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can us `npm qs` node module to stringify your where clause object. Beacuse Loopback is using `qs` under the hood to parse query string.

```
import * as qs from 'qs';

let query = {
  // where condition
}

qs.stringify(query, { addQueryPrefix: true });
```

You can find more info about `qs` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs)

Loopback4 query string issue discussion:- https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/2468

Comment: Thank you Manish. We found a workaround but it would be hard to implement this for all  attributes: "where": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "dicCategoryId": {
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  }
                },